# Is there a way to edit a view that is a modal view form sheet in Xcode 4?

Tags: uiview, xcode4, interface-builder, modalviewcontroller

I made a xib file, but all I can get is either iPad or iPhone view. How can I make it so that the size is the same as a modal view form sheet?

Answer (score 0):

If you drag a view onto the Storyboard and connect it with a modal segue, then click on the segue and set it as form sheet style, it will automatically resize the viewController.  Then, in the view that's presenting the modal view, implement -prepareForSegue.